# Invalid version react-native@0.71.7 for expo sdkVersion 44.0.0. Use react-native@0.64.3

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and doing a project. I tried to install some packages and seems like I have messed up things.

When I try to start expo (expo start/yarn start), I am getting this error:

Started Metro Bundler
Warning: Invalid version react-native@0.71.7 for expo sdkVersion 44.0.0. Use react-native@0.64.3

my package.json looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "4.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "7.1.3",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.2.1",
    "@react-native-segmented-control/segmented-control": "2.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.2.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.1.3",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^7.0.2",
    "expo": "^44.0.6",
    "expo-image-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.71.7",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^15.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.7.2",
    "react-native-paper-dates": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-paper-dropdown": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-share": "^8.2.2",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
```

Highly appreciate any help.

I tried to downgrade react native to 0.64.3 (npm i react-native@0.64.3) and I see this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: laultra@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-native@0.64.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"0.64.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\kalko\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-18T15_43_59_783Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kalko\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-18T15_43_59_783Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried downgrading react to "17.0.1" and that also failed with dependencies with other packages.